# ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace

Tags: мобильные-приложения, pwa

В процессе создания TWA по [данной инструкции](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start) на последнем этапе (build apk с помощью команды `bubblewrap build`) выводится эта ошибка:
`ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace`